# Barryvdh pdf printing output not always the same

Tags: php, css, laravel, pdf

I am using A4 paper on which i need to print 7x2 labels (stickers). They need to fill entire width and height of paper. Now I created it but it is not always same (not sure if this happens because of browsers or printing). What should I change to fix this behavior?

I am iterating over array of objects with adress data.

Here is css I have.

```
    body{
        width:100%;
        font-size: 14px;  
        padding-left: -40px;  
        padding-top: -20px;            
        padding-bottom:-65px;
    }
html{
font-family: DejaVu Sans;   
        text-transform: uppercase;
 }

    .naslovNavadenVelikeCrke {
        font-weight: 900;                 
    }

    .page-break {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
    @page {
        size: A4;
    }
    .container{
      margin-right:40px;
      height: 79px;
      width:49.99%;           
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Not the same how?  For who?  The same computer?  "DejaVu Sans" was the first thing that stuck out to me, are you loading this as a web font?

Comment: If I print page at home everything is fine. But when this is printed in company, whole page is like scaled down (does not fit height and width, so one label contains many texts which should be on separated labels). Dejavu Sans is preinstalled in dompdf.